# mySQL query to gather 2 ids and match them to 2 names per row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Hey all I have an SQL query problem that I have been trying to wrap around my head for a few now and just can not come up with the correct query in order to execute it.

What I am wanting to do is look into 2 tables. Each table has a unique id that matches each other and then a name associated with that id. However, the **OtherTbl** has **both IDs in the same record** instead of **separate** like its in the **UserTbl**.

UserTbl:

```
id | mID   | name
---|-------|-------------
5  | 12345 | Bob Barker
6  | 54688 | Steve Jobs
7  | 56999 | Adam Sandler
9  | 53166 | Bill Gates
11 | 87540 | MC Hammer
```

OtherTbl:

```
id | leftID | rightID
---------------------
8  | 54688  | 12345
41 | 87540  | 87540
43 | 56999  | 53166
```

So what I wanting to get out of those 2 tables above are the 2 users that are together (leftID & rightUD). Something like the below for the output:

```
leftID | rightID | leftName     | rightName
-------|---------|--------------|-----------
54688  | 12345   | Steve Jobs   | Bob Barker
87540  | 87540   | MC Hammer    | MC Hammer
56999  | 53166   | Adam Sandler | Bill Gates
```

I know this can be done - I just cant think of a way in order to make it work!

I tried the tride-and-true inner join's

```
SELECT 
    ut.leftID,
    ut.rightID,
    ot.leftName 
FROM 
    OtherTbl as ot
INNER JOIN 
    UserTbl AS ut 
ON
    ot.leftID = ut.mID
```

This query above does output the data but its not **tied together** like in my example output above. Not to mentioned that its **leaving the users that are on the rightUserFbID**.

An SQL guru would be great to show me what I am missing (or forgetting about being able to use)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the `usertbl` table twice - once for `leftname` (alias `a1`), and another time for `rightname` (alias `a2`).

```
SQL> select b.leftid, b.rightid, a1.name as leftname, a2.name as rightname
  2  from othertbl b join usertbl a1 on a1.mid = b.leftid
  3                  join usertbl a2 on a2.mid = b.rightid;

    LEFTID    RIGHTID LEFTNAME     RIGHTNAME
---------- ---------- ------------ ------------
     54688      12345 Steve Jobs   Bob Barker
     56999      53166 Adam Sandler Bill Gates
     87540      87540 MC Hammer    MC Hammer

SQL>
```

Comment: That was it @Littlefoot! I knew it was possible to do. Thanks for the added knowledge! :o)